# Invalid parameter binding Parameter Name:

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to call a procedure that takes a custom data type of table of Objects as one of the parameters as output. i got an exception that tells Invalid parameter binding Parameter Name: p_list_employe

the signature:

```
FUNCTION   employe.Package.get_employees (  p_Id                IN    VARCHAR2,
                                        p_type          IN    VARCHAR2,
                                        p_code            OUT   VARCHAR2,
                                        p_msg             OUT   VARCHAR2,                                           
                                        p_list_employe         OUT   p_list_employe
                                    )
                            RETURN PLS_INTEGER

  p_list_employe is an object array LIST_EMP as shown here :
  LIST_EMP AS OBJECT
  (       sNumEmp         VARCHAR2(20),  
    sfileNumber          VARCHAR2(20),  
    nDisp          NUMBER(18,0),  
    nUtl         NUMBER(18,0),  
    sType          VARCHAR2(2)
)
```

this is the procedure that am attempting to call:

```
DECLARE
  Return_Value        NUMBER;
  p_code_retour       VARCHAR2(32000);
  p_msg_retour        VARCHAR2(32000);
  p_dot_list_carte    powercard.t_dot_list_carte;
       BEGIN
  Return_Value := employe.Package.get_employees(
    p_Id=>'1',
    p_type=>'2',
    p_code=>p_code,
    p_msg=>p_msg,
    p_list_employe=>p_list_employe);

 dbms_output.put_line('Return_Value=' || Return_Value );   
 dbms_output.put_line('P_CODE=' || P_CODE ); 
 dbms_output.put_line('P_MSG=' || P_MSG ); 
 dbms_output.put_line('p_list_employe(1).sNumEmp=' ||         p_list_employe(1).sNumEmp); 

END;
```

And this is how i call it from my c# code :

```
using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection objConn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(_EMP_CONNECTION))
        {
            try
            {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand objCmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand();
                objCmd.Connection = objConn;

                objCmd.CommandText = "employe.Package.get_employees";
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objCmd.BindByName = true;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("p_Id", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2,7).Value = "123";
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("p_type", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2,2).Value = "02";
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("p_code", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2,3).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("p_msg", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2,350).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

 Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter ParamListEmp= new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("p_list_employe", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Array);
                ParamListEmp.CollectionType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
ParamListEmp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                ParamListEmp.Size = 1024;
ParamListEmp.ArrayBindSize = Enumerable.Repeat(4, 100).ToArray();
 objCmd.Parameters.Add(ParamListEmp);

                objCmd.Parameters.Add("p_return", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                objConn.Open();
                lTrace.AppendLine("* Open Connection => " + objConn.ConnectionString);
                objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it gave an exception like i mentioned , so what am I missing?

Comment: the top code is not a procedure.

Comment: i don't have the procedure the code on top is just to test the call in toadOracle because it's distant

Comment: Please show the procedure signature definition.

Comment: @OldProgrammer i've edited the question by adding the signature.

Comment: @OldProgrammer any news?

Comment: @anass90 Still searching for a solution? Did u try without parameter `p_list_employe`?